# Can cache-control header have multiple values?

Tags: html, angular, meta-tags

`Cache-Control` doesn't seem to work if it has multiple values in Angular 9.

This doesn't work,

```html
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
```

but this works

```html
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-store">
```

Why doesn't the first one work? Is it because `Cache-Control` shouldn't have multiple values or is it because `no-cache`, `no-store` and `must-revalidate` contradicting themselves and thus rendering the whole `meta` tag as `null`?

Answer (score 1):

As per [specs](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2), a header can have multiple values separated by a comma.

> Multiple message-header fields with the same field-name MAY be present
>   in a message if and only if the entire field-value for that header
>   field is defined as a comma-separated list [i.e., #(values)]. It MUST
>   be possible to combine the multiple header fields into one
>   "field-name: field-value" pair, without changing the semantics of the
>   message, by appending each subsequent field-value to the first, each
>   separated by a comma. The order in which header fields with the same
>   field-name are received is therefore significant to the interpretation
>   of the combined field value, and thus a proxy MUST NOT change the
>   order of these field values when a message is forwarded

The problem that you are facing can be because of the order of the properties.

Comment: I know header can multiple values, My question was can Cache-Control have multiple values. I'm afraid, this don't answer my question

Comment: Yes. It can certainly have.